# Windows service deployment with a parameter

Tags: powershell, windows-services, wmi, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to deploy a windows service to remote machine with a parameter being used at service start-up.

I have two issues:

1. How to actually use the Invoke-WmiMethod (powershell) to pass service **with parameters**
2. Starting a service on Windows Server 2012 with a parameter.

ad1) I am publishing service currently like this:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList ("C:\PathToService\ServiceExecutable.exe install") -ComputerName RemoteComputer.local
```

This is done in this way as this is self-installable/uninstallable service. What I tried so far is getting the service object after installing the service like this

```
$(Get-Service -ComputerName RemoteComputer.local -Name ServiceName)
```

but failed to see how I could attach/modify the startup parameters on it.

ad2) This one completely baffles me; 
[image: services dialog]

This is a normal Service dialog since I can remember. Whatever you put into the start parameters should be passed to the service as args.

This just doesn't happen for me on **Windows Server 2012 only!**.

If I run it under Windows 8 - all is well.

If I run it in a console - all is well.

If I run it under Windows Server 2012 through service manager - logs show it fails to get the args.

Does not make any difference if I use different accounts (network, admin,...).

Comment: No, it's not...it is a Windows service

Comment: It's a WCF service hosted as a Windows service.

Comment: Does the "install" start parameter need to stick around permanently, or is only for first start of the service?

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/a/143409/52999 for a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a local `app.config` instead.

That way you can specify all configuration you need, without needing to resort to startup parameters.